# How do I prove a certain set is or isn't an affine subspace? (Specific sets inside)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, proof-writing, affine-geometry

Even knowing the definition of affine subspace, how can I work the definition to prove rigorously what is or isn't an affine subspace? Right now I can see what is or isn't, but I couldn't explain it on an exam, for example.

Examples:

$\{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : b = c,\space a\ge 0\}$

This isn't an affine subspace. My ideia is that it isn't even a vectorial space even though it goes through $(0,0,0)$, but I can't formalize.

$\{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : a+b = 2\}$

This is an affine subspace. It's a plane. How do I formalize? Also, how do I show the dimension is 2?

Other example is a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, of course it is not an affine subspace, but what should I write down to say that it isn't?

Thank you!

Comment: Check the definition of affine subspace again for the first example. It is not correct to argue that it is not a vector space.

Comment: As you were saying, the first example is not an affine subspace and the argument indeed is to show that it is not a linear subspace. To be one, subtracting one element of it from all the others would give a linear subspace. As you were saying, the origin belongs to the subset. IF you subtract the origin from all the elements you get the same set. That set is not a linear subspace since $(1,1,1)$ belongs to it but its opposite $(-1,-1,-1)$ doesn't.

Comment: To show that the second example is an affine subspace, do the same thing. Take an element of the set. For example $(0,2,0)$ and substract it from all other elements of the subset. We get the set $\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:\ x+y=0\right\}$. This is a linear subspace, as you can verify in many ways. For example, it is the kernel of a non-trivial linear functional $(x,y,z)\mapsto x+y$. For the same reason its dimension is one less than that of the whole space.